# How to select data from one table and get all associated records from another table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to simplify my question to best that I can, I hope my explanation will clarify what it means.

The scenario is this:

I have two tables namely: `tbl_instructors` which has the instructors information such as instructor ID and Name and `tbl_advisory` which has the all the records of the class that is being handled by a specific instructor like the `Course`, `Year` and `Section` of the class. So my table is something like this:

**tbl_instructor:**

```
id  | name
----+--------------
001 | Jhon Doe
002 | Kaitlyn Moore
```

**tbl_advisory:**

```
instructor_id  | course        | year      |  section
---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------
001            | BSINT         | 2nd Year  | A
001            | BSINT         | 2nd Year  | C
001            | BSINT         | 2nd Year  | B
002            | BSBA          | 1st Year  | A
002            | BSBA          | 1st Year  | D
```

Now, Im trying to select the instructor Id and Name and its associated advisory information using `INNER JOIN` in my PHP query:

```
<?php
$getAdvisory = "SELECT 
  ti.id AS id,
  ti.name AS name,
  ta.course AS ccourse,
  ta.year AS cyear,
  ta.section AS csection
FROM tbl_instructor as ti
INNER JOIN tbl_advisory as ta
ON ti.id = ta.instructor_id";
OpenConn()->query($getAdvisory);

if ($getAdvisory->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $getAdvisory->fetch_assoc()) {
     $id = $row['id'];
     $name = $row['name'];
    }
    ?>
    <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
    <td><button>View Advisory</button></td>
    <?php
 }
}
?>
```

Which gives me the result set in my html/php table:

```
id   | name          |  action
-----+---------------+-----------
001  | John Doe      | View Advisory
001  | John Doe      | View Advisory
001  | John Doe      | View Advisory
002  | Kaitlyn Moore | View Advisory
002  | Kaitlyn Moore | View Advisory
```

My problem is I want my html table to be DISTINCT by Instructor ID but still return all the the associated advisory information of each Instructor because I want to display what class the instructor is holding in a modal when I click the `View Advisory` button next to every Instructors Name So that I can update my table if the Instructor has removed or added a new Advisory.

How can I achieve it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried `Group By?`

Comment: This is parent page, use group by in there. on click of view advisory pass instructor id to fetch its related advisory from `tbl_advisory` table.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Yes I did. But It only returns 1 row for the advisory information.

Comment: see @RahulMeshram comment above ^

Comment: Can you build test schema in here [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: @RahulMeshram,When I click the View Advisory button the modal will pop up and  display the Advisory Information. .  What are you trying to say ?

Comment: While fetching data for model you don't need to apply group by. You fetch data with the help of instructor id which you will pass on click of view advisory

Comment: @RahulMeshram, Can you post your answer below sir ?

Comment: Check my answer. Let me know if something is not clear

Comment: It seems that you want to transform a 2-dimensional array into a multidimensional one.

Comment: Why aren't you printing any of the information from `tbl_advisory`? What's the point of selecting those columns if you don't use them?

Comment: @Barmar, Please read my question thoroughly. .

Comment: Do the grouping by instructor in the PHP code instead of SQL. When you're fetching the results, create an associative array keyed by instructor ID, and the value is an array of the data from `tbl_advisory`.

Answer (score 0):

You need  DISTINCT clause

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
  ti.id AS id,
  ti.name AS name,
  ta.course AS ccourse,
  ta.year AS cyear,
  ta.section AS csection
FROM tbl_instructor as ti
INNER JOIN tbl_advisory as ta ON ti.id = ta.instructor_id
```

In this way you should obtain

```
id   | name          |  action
-----+---------------+-----------
001  | John Doe      | View Advisory
002  | Kaitlyn Moore | View Advisory
```

If the value are on different rows  the  you could use a  (fake) aggregation function

```
SELECT ti.id AS id,
ti.name AS name,
min(ta.course) AS ccourse,
min(ta.year) AS cyear,
min(ta.section)  AS csection
FROM tbl_instructor as ti
INNER JOIN tbl_advisory as ta ON ti.id = ta.instructor_id
GROUP BY id, name
```

Comment: This won't produce that output, since `course`, `year` and `section` will be different in each row.

Comment: As I asked in a comment to the main question, what's the point of selecting anything from `tbl_advisory` in this query, if it's not being displayed?

Answer (score -1):

Plis check this query :

```
SELECT    ti.*, GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( ta.course, ' ' , ta.year,' ', ta.section ) separator ' - ') as ColumnName 
FROM tbl_instructor as ti
INNER JOIN tbl_advisory as ta ON ti.id = ta.instructor_id 
GROUP BY ti.idid
```

Output:

```
      | name          |  action
 -----+---------------+-----------
 001  | John Doe      | BSINT 2nd Year a - BSINT 2nd Year b - BSINT 2nd Year c
 002  | Kaitlyn Moore | BSBA 1st Year d - BSBA 1st Year a
```

Comment: Thanks for this, But I want to assign the Course, Year and Section into PHP variable so that I can update the database when the Instructor added or removed an advisory . Is that possible with this query ?

Comment: You can use `explode(',', $row['ColumnName'])` to convert the column into an array of all the advisories.